# Where is the addons path for Openerp 6.1 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, module, odoo

I installed openerp 6.1 in Ubuntu and i tried to install a new module that i programmed and tested in anothers openerp 6.1 in Windows. I tried to copy the module folder in the path /usr/share/openerp/addons, but the module is not detected when i update the modules list in openerp.
Also i tried to modify openerp-server.conf adding the line

```
addons_path = /home/daniel/addonsopenerp
```

and starting openerp with the command

```
openerp-server -c
```

My question is: How can i install my own modules in openerp 6.1 in Ubuntu?

Comment: No, as you can read; ...but the module is not detected when i update the modules list in openerp.

Comment: now all the modules in /home/daniel/addonsopenerp path right?

Comment: I tried to put the module in /usr/share/openerp/addons and also i tried in /home/daniel/addonsopenerp and don't works.

Comment: Did you checked access rights of the modules? in ubuntu it can be one of the issue.

Comment: What access rights i need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146742/discussion-between-viki-chavada-and-daniel-ruiz).